# How do I add a foreign key constraint to an existing table in a MySQL database in python using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, pymysql

I can define a function that will add the table to the database and designate the primary key if given. But I can't make the function designate any foreign key(s) if given. Here is the function:

```
def add_table(table, table_name, primary_key = None, foreign_key_dict = None):
    """This function adds the table to the db, designates the 
    primary key if given, and outputs the 
    first 5 rows of the table for verification"""
    
    # get the dtypes of the columns in the table
    dtypes = table.dtypes
    
    # convert columns and dtypes to dictionary for schema
    dtypes_dict = dtypes.to_dict()
    
    # make empty dictionary to build schema
    schema = {}
    print(table)
    
    # iterate through columns in table to build schema dict
    for col in table.columns:
        print(col)
        
        # set schema for ints
        if table[col].dtype == 'int64':
            schema[col] = Integer()
            
        elif table[col].dtype == 'float64':
            schema[col] = Float()
            
        elif table[col].dtype == 'object':
            
            # get max length of the column
            max_len = table[col].fillna('').map(len).max()
            
            # set schema for primary key
            if col == primary_key:
                schema[col] = String(max_len + 1)
                print(max_len + 1)
                print("string")
                
            else:
                schema[col] = Text(max_len + 1)
                print(max_len + 1)
                print("text")
    
    # save table to movies db
    table.to_sql(table_name, 
                engine, 
                dtype = schema,
                if_exists = 'replace',
                index = False)
    
    # set primary key column if necessary
    if primary_key is not None:
        engine.execute(f'ALTER TABLE {table_name} \
                       ADD PRIMARY KEY (`{primary_key}`);')
        print("added primary key")
        ## FUNCTION WORKS UP UNTIL HERE

    # set foreign key column(s) if necessary
    if foreign_key_dict is not None:
        
        for key, value in foreign_key_dict.items():

            engine.execute(f'ALTER TABLE {table_name} \
                           ADD FOREIGN KEY (`{key}`(37)) \
                           REFERENCES {value[0]} (`{value[1]}`);')
            print("added foreign key")
         
    # FUNCTION WORKS AFTER THIS COMMENT IF FOREIGN KEY
    # IS NONE
    # check table by printing first five rows
    print(f"First five rows of {table_name} table:\n")
    
    sql = f"""SELECT *
    FROM {table_name}
    LIMIT 5;
    """
    
    result = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
    print(result)
    
    # check the primary key
    sql = f"""
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{db_name}'
    AND TABLE_NAME = '{table_name}'
    AND COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI';
    """
    result = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
    
    if not result.empty:
        primary_key_column = result.iloc[0]['COLUMN_NAME']
        print(f"The primary key of {table_name} is {primary_key_column}.")
    else:
        print(f"The {table_name} table doesn't have a primary key.")
    
    # print empy lines for readability
    print('\n\n')
```

Here is the dictionary used in calling the function:

```
table_dict = {
    "course_offerings":    {"df": course_offerings, 
                            "primary_key": 'uuid',
                            "fk_dict": {'course_uuid': ("courses", 'uuid')}},
    "courses":             {"df": courses, 
                            "primary_key": 'uuid',
                            "fk_dict": None},
    "instructors":         {"df": instructors, 
                            "primary_key": 'id',
                            "fk_dict": None},
    "rooms":               {"df": rooms, 
                            "primary_key": 'uuid',
                            "fk_dict": None},
    "schedules":           {"df": schedules, 
                            "primary_key": 'uuid',
                            "fk_dict": None},
    "sections":            {"df": sections, 
                            "primary_key": 'uuid',
                            "fk_dict": {'course_offering_uuid': ("course_offerings", 'uuid'), 
                                        'room_uuid': ("rooms", 'uuid'), 
                                        'schedule_uuid': ("schedules", 'uuid')}},
    "subject_memberships": {"df": subject_memberships, 
                            "primary_key": None,
                            "fk_dict": {'course_offering_uuid': ("course_offerings", 'uuid'), 
                                        'subject_code': ("subjects", 'code')}},
    "subjects":            {"df": subjects, 
                            "primary_key": 'code',
                            "fk_dict": None},
    "teachings":           {"df": teachings, 
                            "primary_key": None,
                            "fk_dict": {'instructor_id': ("instructors", 'id'), 
                                        'section_uuid': ("sections", 'uuid')}},
    "grade_distributions": {"df": grade_distributions, 
                            "primary_key": None,
                            "fk_dict": {'course_offering_uuid': ("course_offerings", 'uuid')}}
}
```

Here is the line that calls the function:

```
for key, value in table_dict.items():
    add_table(value['df'], key, value['primary_key'], value['fk_dict'])
```

Here is the output and error I am getting, an Integrity Error:

```
                                       uuid  \
0      344b3ebe-da7e-314c-83ed-9425269695fd   
1      f718e6cd-33f0-3c14-a9a6-834d9c3610a8   
2      ea3b717c-d66b-30dc-8b37-964d9688295f   
3      075da420-5f49-3dd0-93df-13e3c152e1b1   
4      2b4e216d-a728-3713-8c7c-19afffc6b2fd   
...                                     ...   
81447  3573e335-e7be-33a6-b023-8704b3acc93b   
81448  5d437083-a1d0-38b8-aa70-ec3564da39a6   
81449  13278922-0726-3823-abda-dc14df03d8a6   
81450  fd039fe4-32ec-31dd-a142-c7db54df784b   
81451  4e151e41-fdfb-3176-a96a-bec0715492a3   

                                course_uuid  term_code  \
0      a3e3e1c3-543d-3bb5-ae65-5f2aec4ad1de       1092   
1      a3e3e1c3-543d-3bb5-ae65-5f2aec4ad1de       1082   
2      a3e3e1c3-543d-3bb5-ae65-5f2aec4ad1de       1172   
3      a3e3e1c3-543d-3bb5-ae65-5f2aec4ad1de       1114   
4      a3e3e1c3-543d-3bb5-ae65-5f2aec4ad1de       1104   
...                                     ...        ...   
81447  4a7f3d9d-f2e5-3df2-8dee-2c2d02ed9098       1182   
81448  1220244c-2bbf-3169-8eb0-6a2da36f40f6       1182   
81449  516f637c-a244-3df0-ba3f-f11ce650543d       1182   
81450  fbe0838f-9469-3d83-ad85-91ba5aabd1a3       1182   
81451  1b17abd5-39f9-3a2c-8eda-a88bf1871221       1182   

                                 name  
0          Cooperative Education Prog  
1          Cooperative Education Prog  
2          Cooperative Education Prog  
3          Cooperative Education Prog  
4          Cooperative Education Prog  
...                               ...  
81447           Conservation Planning  
81448                             NaN  
81449  Patient Ed. as Advocacy Strat.  
81450   Multid. Appr. to Colon Cancer  
81451                             NaN  

[81452 rows x 4 columns]
uuid
37
string
course_uuid
37
text
term_code
name
31
text
added primary key
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1819, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1818     if not evt_handled:
-> 1819         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1820             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1821         )
   1823 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:732, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    731 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 732     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:148, in Cursor.execute(self, query, args)
    146 query = self.mogrify(query, args)
--> 148 result = self._query(query)
    149 self._executed = query

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:310, in Cursor._query(self, q)
    309 self._clear_result()
--> 310 conn.query(q)
    311 self._do_get_result()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:548, in Connection.query(self, sql, unbuffered)
    547 self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
--> 548 self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
    549 return self._affected_rows

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:775, in Connection._read_query_result(self, unbuffered)
    774     result = MySQLResult(self)
--> 775     result.read()
    776 self._result = result

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:1156, in MySQLResult.read(self)
   1155 try:
-> 1156     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
   1158     if first_packet.is_ok_packet():

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:725, in Connection._read_packet(self, packet_type)
    724         self._result.unbuffered_active = False
--> 725     packet.raise_for_error()
    726 return packet

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py:221, in MysqlPacket.raise_for_error(self)
    220     print("errno =", errno)
--> 221 err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py:143, in raise_mysql_exception(data)
    142     errorclass = InternalError if errno < 1000 else OperationalError
--> 143 raise errorclass(errno, errval)

IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 3
      1 # test adding one
      2 for key, value in table_dict.items():
----> 3     add_table(value['df'], key, value['primary_key'], value['fk_dict'])

Cell In [6], line 61, in add_table(table, table_name, primary_key, foreign_key_dict)
     57 if foreign_key_dict is not None:
     59     for key, value in foreign_key_dict.items():
---> 61         engine.execute(f'ALTER TABLE {table_name} \
     62                        ADD FOREIGN KEY (`{key}`(37)) \
     63                        REFERENCES {value[0]} (`{value[1]}`);')
     64         print("added foreign key")
     66 # check table by printing first five rows

File <string>:2, in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py:402, in _decorate_with_warning.<locals>.warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    400 if not skip_warning:
    401     _warn_with_version(message, version, wtype, stacklevel=3)
--> 402 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3176, in Engine.execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   3158 """Executes the given construct and returns a
   3159 :class:`_engine.CursorResult`.
   3160 
   (...)
   3173 
   3174 """
   3175 connection = self.connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 3176 return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1291, in Connection.execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1282 if isinstance(statement, util.string_types):
   1283     util.warn_deprecated_20(
   1284         "Passing a string to Connection.execute() is "
   1285         "deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.  Use the "
   (...)
   1288         "driver-level SQL string."
   1289     )
-> 1291     return self._exec_driver_sql(
   1292         statement,
   1293         multiparams,
   1294         params,
   1295         _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS,
   1296         future=False,
   1297     )
   1299 try:
   1300     meth = statement._execute_on_connection

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1595, in Connection._exec_driver_sql(self, statement, multiparams, params, execution_options, future)
   1585         (
   1586             statement,
   1587             distilled_params,
   (...)
   1591             statement, distilled_parameters, execution_options
   1592         )
   1594 dialect = self.dialect
-> 1595 ret = self._execute_context(
   1596     dialect,
   1597     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_statement,
   1598     statement,
   1599     distilled_parameters,
   1600     execution_options,
   1601     statement,
   1602     distilled_parameters,
   1603 )
   1605 if not future:
   1606     if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1862, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1859             branched.close()
   1861 except BaseException as e:
-> 1862     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
   1863         e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1864     )
   1866 return result

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:2043, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   2041     util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
   2042 elif should_wrap:
-> 2043     util.raise_(
   2044         sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   2045     )
   2046 else:
   2047     util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:208, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    207 try:
--> 208     raise exception
    209 finally:
    210     # credit to
    211     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    212     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    213     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1819, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1817                 break
   1818     if not evt_handled:
-> 1819         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1820             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1821         )
   1823 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:
   1824     self.dispatch.after_cursor_execute(
   1825         self,
   1826         cursor,
   (...)
   1830         context.executemany,
   1831     )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:732, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    731 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 732     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:148, in Cursor.execute(self, query, args)
    144     pass
    146 query = self.mogrify(query, args)
--> 148 result = self._query(query)
    149 self._executed = query
    150 return result

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:310, in Cursor._query(self, q)
    308 self._last_executed = q
    309 self._clear_result()
--> 310 conn.query(q)
    311 self._do_get_result()
    312 return self.rowcount

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:548, in Connection.query(self, sql, unbuffered)
    546     sql = sql.encode(self.encoding, "surrogateescape")
    547 self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
--> 548 self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
    549 return self._affected_rows

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:775, in Connection._read_query_result(self, unbuffered)
    773 else:
    774     result = MySQLResult(self)
--> 775     result.read()
    776 self._result = result
    777 if result.server_status is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:1156, in MySQLResult.read(self)
   1154 def read(self):
   1155     try:
-> 1156         first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
   1158         if first_packet.is_ok_packet():
   1159             self._read_ok_packet(first_packet)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:725, in Connection._read_packet(self, packet_type)
    723     if self._result is not None and self._result.unbuffered_active is True:
    724         self._result.unbuffered_active = False
--> 725     packet.raise_for_error()
    726 return packet

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py:221, in MysqlPacket.raise_for_error(self)
    219 if DEBUG:
    220     print("errno =", errno)
--> 221 err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\dojo-env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py:143, in raise_mysql_exception(data)
    141 if errorclass is None:
    142     errorclass = InternalError if errno < 1000 else OperationalError
--> 143 raise errorclass(errno, errval)

IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
[SQL: ALTER TABLE course_offerings                            ADD FOREIGN KEY (`course_uuid`(37))                            REFERENCES courses (`uuid`);]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this error? How can I create the foreign key? Thank you!